# Water beyond 10.3 metres

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]Using a centrifugal pump, you can only pump upto 10 metres. Thats fine.

But,

Can't i pump water beyond 10.3 metres by placing the suction head exactly at 10 metres( or below that) and extending the delivery pipe to some 13 metres ???

Comment: I don't understand where the 10 meters bound comes from and I get the impression that the reason for the bound is relevant to your proposal.. could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Why not put the pump below the surface and not waste pump energy of suction?

Comment: centrifugal pump of suction type is what i am referring to @france95

Answer (score 2):

> Using a centrifugal pump, you can only pump upto 10 metres.

Your assertion is not quite right: There are centrifugal pumps that can pump water way higher than 10.3 metres (e.g. [these monsters](https://impeller.net/magazine/news_en/doc2582x.asp)).

The 10.3 metres is a limit on the suction height, i.e. the height of the pump above the water source ([see maximum suction explanation](http://processengineering.co.uk/article/2019233/maximum-suction)). Excessive suction head will result in the pressure on the suction side falling below the vapour pressure of the water, turning it into vapour, which is not desirable for a centrifugal pump ([see this Ref](https://www.grundfos.com/service-support/encyclopedia-search/suction-lift.html)).

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I didn't get the answer for what i really asked ! I have added a figure in my question. Please do refer :)

Comment: dear @Vinayak I reviewed your question and I don't think moving the position of the pump and adding the last pipe is gonna change the limit. The fact is that this limit is caused by pressure of the water, meaning that you will keep the power of your pump lower than that needed to reach the 10 meters. The only thing that matters here is how much power you put into the system, not in which point you locate it.

Comment: @Vinayak the suction height is the height on the left of your diagram.